# What time-related powers has Dr. Strange demonstrated in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, doctor-strange

In the MCU, the Eye of Agamotto houses the Time Stone, and Dr. Strange has demonstrated numerous powers, including:

- ageing/deageing fruit
- trapping Dormamu in a repeating time loop
- seeing 14,000,605 possible futures

However, as I understand it, in the comics, [the Eye of Agamotto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Agamotto) is not related to the Time Stone and imbues powers primarily related to mystical "seeing":

> The Eye is a weapon of wisdom that can radiate a powerful mystical light that allows Strange to see through all disguises and illusions, see past events, and track both ethereal and corporeal beings by their psychic or magical emissions.

**What time-related powers has Dr. Strange demonstrated in the comics?  Are they tied to objects in particular?**

(This is somewhat of interest since it may set some precedent for what Dr. Strange can now do in the MCU given he no longer possesses the Eye.)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190680/has-doctor-strange-ever-traveled-in-time-without-the-use-of-the-infinity-stone?rq=1

Comment: To the VTCers:   This is clearly not a dupe.   The other question asks about time-travel.   (Actually it asks about the limited form of relativistic time-travel that arises from teleportation, and the answer answers about time travel in general.)  However, I am clearly asking about more.   I even gave **three!** examples in the question of time-related powers that are NOT time-travel.

Comment: not a dupe (at the moment) because this one asks about the comics, and the other is targeting the MCU

Comment: Point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMqZ2PPOLik Counterpoint: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War#Sharon_Carter_/_Agent_13

Answer (score 2):

His master had some candles that allowed for time travel. They would send a target creature to another time, and the target had until the flame went out to return or be lost forever in the other time.

[image: Time candles]

Source: Strange Tales #124

Supposedly Strange inherited a supply of those when he became Supreme Sorcerer.

In a later adventure he took a woman back in time just by "riding along the ripples on the waves of time":

[image: Time riding]

Source: Dr. Strange #17

Answer (score -2):

Well, as was pointed out [elsewhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190680/has-doctor-strange-ever-traveled-in-time-without-the-use-of-the-infinity-stone?rq=1), Strange has shown the ability to travel in time with *just* his mystic arts.

Also, I'd argue, his functional immortality (granted when he defeated Death in the classic Englehart/Brunner run) might be considered time-related.